Heavily Customized Salesforce org reformatting my custom global actions, cannot find way to override
Currently have a screen flow that uses an LWC to have that screen flow show up as a global action. When I open up the global action on my accounts page, it gives me the first photo. When I Open the global action on my setup page, it looks like the second. The accounts page has been heavily customized through using a vendor called practifi, and I am trying to find a way to get around their auto formatting of my global action.


<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

    <lightning:card title="Create New Entity Flow" class="slds-card custom-modal-container">
        <div class="flow-container">
            <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" />
        </div>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>


({
    init: function (component, event, helper) {
        var flow = component.find("flowData");
        flow.startFlow("Create_New_Entity_Flow");
    }
})

    .THIS .custom-modal-container {
    height: 600px; /* Set the fixed height */
    overflow: hidden; /* Prevent overflow outside the modal */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.THIS .flow-container {
    flex: 1;
    overflow-y: auto; /* Enable vertical scrolling */
}


Found a work around to my problem, just configuring footers and putting in my own next button fixed everything
